# TypeScript in browser: Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Identifier

Tags: typescript

First of all, I've heard that modern browsers are able to run TypeScript even without compiling it into JavaScript. If this assumption is wrong, please let me know, and this is the problem here.

In case I did understand correctly, my TypeScript code doesn't work in the browser. Here is the error:

[image]

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> First of all, I've heard that modern browsers are able to run TypeScript even without compiling it into JavaScript

You've heard wrong. You need to compile to JavaScript.

You *can* use a script tag that has TypeScript in it ... but it will still compile to JavaScript before being passed to the Browser runtime. E.g. : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

Comment: is right. However you can debug the typescript files on your development computer using the browser developer tools